# Read directories from a drive/folder in a Windows 8 Store app?

Tags: c#, windows-8

Is there any way to read for example all the directories/files in a drive/folder within a Windows 8 Store application? I have googled and nothing except reading the known folders (documents, pictures, etc.), maybe you guys/girls can help me out.

Thanks!

Comment: Since you have limited write access to folders while being a Windows 8 Store application I would simply use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.knownfolders.aspx to get a list of the folders you can actually write to.

Comment: Is there no way to read the whole drive?

Comment: You wouldn't be able to write outside of certain directories so there isn't an easy way.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to scan directories for .avi, .wmv, etc. for a smaller xmbc kind of application. Show movie posters and info about the movie etc.

Comment: There should be a way to integrate the results of a Windows search into your program. Here is something interesting: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465238.aspx just provide a method for the user to filter certain file types.  This should allow you to get the full directory for each file and thus handle playing the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In WinStore app, access to files/folders is restricted.

You have access to app's installation folder, accessible by Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.

And you can access known folders (docs, pictures, videos, etc), through KnownFolders class. You have to decrare the appropriate capability. For example, if you need access to VideosLibrary folder, you have to define VideosLibrary capability.

Files from other locations are accessible only by FilePicker.

For more info, please, look at:

[KnownFolders class (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.knownfolders.aspx)

[File access and permissions in Windows Store apps (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967755.aspx)

[App capability declarations (Windows Store apps) (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464936.aspx)

[Integrating with file picker contracts(Windows Store apps) (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465174.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, you can't scan an arbitrary folder/drive on the system. WinRT APIs limit your reach to the user's "Known Folders".

This is consistent with the rest of the Windows experience, where all media are expected to live in their respective libraries. You wouldn't need to look for movies outside the Video library.

Answer (score 0):

You can access drive and folder in this way but it require capabilities to be turned on from packageManifest

StorageFolder folder5 = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(@"Z:\");