# Recursive through Pictures Library in Windows Store Javascript Application

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winjs

I would like to access all of the image files within the Pictures Library, and I read through the articles mentioned at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13360436/read-directories-from-a-drive-folder-in-a-windows-8-store-app).  I thought about using a deep query, but it takes too long to get all of the files within the pictures library (I'm dealing with 1TB of pictures for testing).

What I would like to do is start at the root of the pictures library and get all of the pictures and folders at root then go into the folders and recursively inwards.

I would start with

```
    Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.picturesLibrary.getFoldersAsync().then(function (folders)
    {
        handleFolders(folders);
    });
```

And me handle folders function would look something like this, though I know there is no overload for getFilesAsync or getFoldersAsync that takes a folder as a parameter.

```
function handleFolders(folders)
{
    if (folders.size > 0)
    {
        Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.picturesLibrary.getFilesAsync(folders).then(function (files)
        {
            handleFiles(files);
            for(var i = 0; i < folders.size; i++)
            {
                Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.picturesLibrary.getFoldersAsync(folders).then(function (recFolders)
                {
                    handleFolders(recFolders);
                });
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        var x = folders;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that picturesLibrary is just a well-known instance of StorageFolder.

Something like this should get you closer (adjustment may be needed depending on whether you're looking for depth first or breadth first listing):

```
handleFolders([ Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.picturesLibrary ]);

function handleFolders(folders) {
    for (var i = 0; i < folders.length; i++) {
        console.log("Folder: " + folders[i].name);

        folders[i].getFilesAsync().then(function (files) {
            handleFiles(files);
        });

        folders[i].getFoldersAsync().then(function(folders)
        {
            handleFolders(folders);
        });
    }
}
function handleFiles(files) {
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
        console.log("File: " + files[i].name);
}
```