# Creating Array of Images with source from a given folder C# Windows Desktop

Tags: c#, arrays, image, windows-8

Hello Everyone as the title says im trying to create array of type Image and set the source of the images in it from a folder because i have 52 png's in the folder and i dont want to add them one by one.. so is there a way to do this ?
That's what i got so far:

```
        void DeckCard()
    {
        Image []Deck=new Image[52];
        for(int i=0;i<=Deck.Length;i++)
        {
            Deck[i] = new Image();
            LayoutRoot.Children.Add(Deck[i]);
            Deck[i].Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);     
            Deck[i].Height = 400;
            Deck[i].Width = 200;

        }
    }
```

P.S. the folder location is Assets//Cards/(here are the pictures)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read directories from a drive/folder in a Windows 8 Store app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13360436/read-directories-from-a-drive-folder-in-a-windows-8-store-app)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-AR/library/bb397926.aspx) and [Directory.GetFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getfiles(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Image[] deck = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("Assets\\Cards\\")
                        .Select(file => System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(file))
                        .ToArray();
```

## EDIT

---

I have never developed a Windows Store application, but here is my try (note that I did not attempt to compile the following code):

```
Image[] cards = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFolderAsync("Assets\\Cards").GetResults()
                       .GetFilesAsync().GetResults()
                       .Select(file =>
{
       using(IRandomAccessStream fileStream = file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read).GetResults())
       {
           Image image = new Image();
           BitmapImage source = new BitmapImage();
           source.SetSourceAsync(fileStream).GetResults();
           image.Source = source;

           // Modify Image properties here...
           // image.Margin = new Thicknes(0, 0, 0, 0);
           // ....

           // You can also do LayoutRoot.Children.Add(image);

           return image;
       }
}).ToArray();
```

Phew, that was harsh!

Of course this code can be nicely refactored using [async/await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx).

Comment: Note if there are any other files in this directory that aren't images this can throw exceptions

Comment: Hi i cant seem to use "Directory" and .FromFile i have the System.IO library loaded but it wont work

Comment: @Assim Did you add `using System.IO`?

Comment: @MatiasCicero or fully qualifying the names, if the OP has clashing classes i.e. `System.IO.Directory.GetFiles`

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Thanks for the tip. Changed my answer and added the corresponding namespaces

Comment: @Assim You should also have `System.Linq` and `System.Drawing` referenced

Comment: i have the System.Linq but i cant add the System.Drawing library why is that ?

Comment: @Assim Are you trying to develop a `Windows Store App`? Not all classes from `System.IO` are supported right now for those projects.

Comment: @Assim you need to add a reference to `System.Drawing` in the project

Comment: @Assim In which case take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13360436/read-directories-from-a-drive-folder-in-a-windows-8-store-app

Comment: You can check all the supported classes [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh454050.aspx). See that there is no `System.IO.Directory`. If i'm not mistaken, [StorageFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefolder) provides similar functionality and you can use it in a Windows App. I'll read the documentation a bit and come with a new answer.

Comment: @MatiasCicero No need see the potential duplicate I've linked

Comment: @TheLethalCoder It's ok. It's nice reading into unknown stuff :P

Comment: @Assim Please check if my updated answer solves your problem.

Comment: it seems that there are a lot mistakes in it http://prntscr.com/8x1k34 and also with expanded error list http://prntscr.com/8x1kmi

Comment: i cant find any variable named storageFolder in case you wanted to do StorageFolder that doesn't contains a .result function and also ContinueWith is giving me an error as well http://prntscr.com/8x1lrk

Comment: @Assim My bad, I did not mean to write `storageFolder` but `assetsFolder` instead, see my update. This is what happens when I can't compile my answers :P

Comment: now only the error with ContinueWith is left http://prntscr.com/8x1ms7 im really grateful for helping me man !

Comment: @MatiasCicero The OP seems unwilling to learn I think you've got to the point where you're doing their work for them not helping them anymore

Comment: well sorry but im new to c# and this is entirely new to me so it's hard to figure out how to fix it ..

Comment: @Assim It seems `Task<T>.ContinueWith` is not supported on WIndows Store Apps, try my new code which uses `GetResult()`

Comment: @Assim Try `GetResults` instead of `GetResult` (with an `s` at the end)

Comment: that fixed the second GetResult but the first one is giving an error with .Select http://prntscr.com/8x1t1m

Comment: @Assim Do you have `using System.Linq;`?

Comment: I was missing it now everything is almost done but again there's error with .ToArray() method at the end http://prntscr.com/8x1urn

Comment: fixed ! it works finally with no errors ! awesome job man thank you for the help

Comment: @Assim Always glad to help! If you manage to run it and it outputs the expected result then feel free to mark this as an answer :)

Comment: 1 last newbie qusetion how do i attach this to my actual array of images

Comment: @Assim You should not have the original array anymore, this code should replace yours. If you need to modify the Image properties or do something with it when it's created you can see my updated answer. I added comments to where you can put your code.

Answer (score 1):

Well you've got to find the images in the directory.
Have a look at `System.IO.Directory.GetFiles` especially the `SearchPattern` overload. And if they are png's it might look something like this:

```
string[] straImageLocations = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("DirectoryLocation", "*.png", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```

The Search pattern is `*` -> Wildcard to match any characters, `.png` where it ends in ".png".

You then have the locations of all the files and all you need to do is load them into an image array. Along the lines of the following:

```
Image[] Deck = new Image[straImageLocations.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < straImageLocations.Length; i++)
{
    Deck[i] = Image.FromFile(straImageLocations[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out it's speaks on Enumerating Files within a given directory: [Enumerate Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles(v=vs.110).aspx)

This is more efficient than GetFiles due to the fact that you have to wait until all the file names are returned from GetFiles to start using it. Enumerate allows you to start before this.

[Enumerate Vs GetFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2(v=vs.110).aspx)